# Variable scope in Jade

Tags: node.js, pug

I have simple question. For example i have code bellow in jade file

```
block content
    - var i = 0;  // 'first declaring'

    div#id
        p #{i}   // don't change !?   item = {'one', 'two', ...} for example
    button(onclick="next()") click

    script.
      var i = 0;   // 'second declaring'
      function next() {
      console.log(i);  
      var myid = document.getElementById("id");    
      myid.innerHTML = "#{items[i].a"
      i++;
    };
```

My Question: What is the difference between 'first declaring' and 'second declaring' var i = 0. How do I change the global value from 'first declaring' from function next().

Answer (score 0):

Jade will compile this template into function, so to see code just compile this template into js file manually - see http://jade-lang.com/api/ for samples. IMHO, myid.innerHTML will not be compiled by jade, so it will be in html in raw form. Maybe i m wrong, just look at compiled code.